# .aab crash constantly on every new build

Tags: android, react-native

Building the app with command like below to get `.aab` file, it does get generated successfully. However the `.aab` file that is firstly generated tends to crash constantly (when building in a clean environment).

**clean environment here i'm referring to..

1. newly clone project, then build `.aab`
2. building inside CI pipeline (project cloned, install dependency, build `.aab`)
3. by removing the `build` folder inside /android/app

```
# Building .aab file
cd android && ENVFILE=.uat.env ./gradlew bundleRelease

# Installing app to device from .aab file
bundletool build-apks --bundle=app-release.aab --output=release.apks && Bundletool install-apks --apks=release.apks --device-id=6dgul7eeaea6eiln
```

I'm fully aware of [this issue (App Crash in Release Build --- FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context #30761)](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30761) and our app is on React Native 0.64.2. So according to React Native changelog, this issue should be resolved in [0.63.4](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/53f55001afbf07494de0df064a92dfdd42f37c98)

**My crash logs as per below**

```
03-23 23:35:17.102 25619 25647 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
03-23 23:35:17.102 25619 25647 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.app.app, PID: 25619
03-23 23:35:17.102 25619 25647 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
03-23 23:35:17.102 25619 25647 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
03-23 23:35:17.102 25619 25647 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(Unknown Source:2)
03-23 23:35:17.102 25619 25647 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(Unknown Source:10)
03-23 23:35:17.102 25619 25647 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(Unknown Source:18)
03-23 23:35:17.102 25619 25647 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.p.p(Unknown Source:189)
03-23 23:35:17.102 25619 25647 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.p.c(Unknown Source:0)
03-23 23:35:17.102 25619 25647 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.p$e.run(Unknown Source:68)
03-23 23:35:17.102 25619 25647 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

We don't have intention to upgrade to latest RN version for now, but would like to understand if there's a way to fix this.

For now, our solution is to rebuild the `.aab` on second time to ensure it's working fine.

Comment: Metro is used during development phase, so if the compile package asks something about Metro then you didn't compiled for RELEASE.

Comment: @emandt the app is certainly build for release, like I've explained.. on subsequent build it will work. Even for uploading to Google PlayStore as well.

Comment: Uploading an APK/AAB doesn't means it is in Release......However if you're sure it is compiled for Release then I cannot help you because I'm sure Metro is not included in APK/AAB but "exists" only during development/building and not in Runtime on mobile platform.

Comment: How do you confirm yourself building a Release variant `.aab` file then?

Comment: By reading AndroidManifest.xml inside APK/AAB and check for "debuggable:true". If it is present, it was built for Debug.

Comment: Just checked, it's not there. So do yo usually build release variant aab / apk?